# How to apply a list with n elements to a function with n arguments?

Tags: functions, programming

The Multinomial function has n arguments.

For educational purposes I want to calculate Multinomial over a list (of solutions of the FrobeniusSolve function) like:

```
FrobeniusSolve[Array[1 &, 3], 3] // Reverse
```

So, I did:

```
Map[Multinomial[#] &, Reverse[FrobeniusSolve[Array[1 &, 3], 3]]]
```

And... this did not work as expected, no errors or warnings however.

Is there a simple way to input {x1,x2,x3} to Multinomial as Multinomial[x1,x2,x3] ?

There must be. What am I overlooking?

Comment: Are you looking for ``Multinomial @@@ Reverse[FrobeniusSolve[ConstantArray[1, 3], 3]]`` ?

Comment: Perhaps `Apply[Multinomial[#] &, Reverse[FrobeniusSolve[Array[1 &, 3], 3]]]` is what you're looking for?

Comment: @Domen I'm 17 seconds to late ;-)

Comment: @UlrichNeumann, I think you should add ``{1}`` as the level for ``Apply`` (second argument, then it is the same as mine) :-)

Comment: @UlrichNeumann That results in {1,1,1} ... Not Ok

Comment: @Domen That looks a lot like what I want. Thank you very much. Not that I understand it completely yet, but it works.

Comment: @Domen Thanks for your hint

Comment: To help the understanding: `Multinomial[Sequence @@ #] & /@ 
 Reverse[FrobeniusSolve[ConstantArray[1, 3], 3]]`

Comment: Starting with v13.1 there is now [`MapApply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapApply.html), i.e., `MapApply[f, expr]` or `MapApply[f][expr]` is `f@@@expr`

Comment: Sequence @@ etc. only works if the lists have length 3. - What if I supply a list with m elements?

Comment: @niloderoock, this is unusual, it should work for any number of elements in a list. Can you please show an example where it doesn't work?

Comment: Thx for your reply! I will, tomorrow in my timezone. It is dinnertime here.

Comment: Yes, it works in all cases. I got confused by the @@ notation for Apply. In case you might be interested I worked on explaining the Multinomial Theorem. A step in my explanation was: g[m_, n_] := 
 Map[Multinomial[Apply[Sequence, #]] Apply[Times, 
     Apply[Power, {Table[Subscript[x, k], {k, 1, m}], #}]] &, 
  Reverse[FrobeniusSolve[ConstantArray[1, m], n]]]
Thanks again for your help! ;-)

Comment: @BobHanlon Not all my students have 13.1 :-(

Comment: @BobHanlon If they have MMa at all!

Comment: @Domen I am confused... Did you use 13.1 code in your answer?

Comment: No, I used 12.3. The syntax with triple @@@ has been implemented in Mathematica ever since [version 4](https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v4/RefGuide/Apply.html). It is only the named symbol ``MapApply`` that has been added in version 13.1.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. All new for me. :-(   (I am "still" on 13.0, which has been fine.)